# how to find users who visited my site more than 3 days out of 7 days?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find users who are all visit my page for more than 3 days out of 7 days and 15 days and 30 days

I find total users who visit my site and count based on the user but it never matches my result

my collection is like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf110a80556ac496396d07c"),
    "user" : "sachin",
    "event" : "page-navigation",
    "data" : {
        "url" : "/"
    },
    "addedAt" : ISODate("2019-05-14T11:31:52.755Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf110a80556ac496396d07c"),
    "user" : "sachin",
    "event" : "page-navigation",
    "data" : {
        "url" : "/"
    },
    "addedAt" : ISODate("2019-05-15T11:31:52.755Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf110a80556ac496396d07c"),
    "user" : "sachin",
    "event" : "page-navigation",
    "data" : {
        "url" : "/"
    },
    "addedAt" : ISODate("2019-05-16T11:31:52.755Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

etc... consider upto 45days

please ignore the _id and from the above sample data Sachin visited my website  for 3 days within 1week and like that so many visits 3days out of 7 days

```
db.getCollection('usertracks').aggregate([ 
    {$project: {
            yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$addedAt", timezone: "+05:30" } }
    }},
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: {
                addedAt: "$yearMonthDay",
                user: "$user"
        },
            users: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
])
```

If any users visit my website for more than 3 days out of 7 days it should return that user details. Help me to find a solution.

Thanks for your help!

output:

```
{
  "user":"Sachin"
}
```

Comment: find users who visit more than 3 days out of 7 days? the output should object contain user who visits more than 3 days

Answer (score 0):

```
const getUserCategoryDetails = async function(){

const activeUsers = await UserTrack.aggregate([ 
    {
        $project: {
            yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format:  "%Y/%m/%d", date: "$addedAt", timezone: "+05:30" } },
            user:"$user"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id:"$user",
            "visitedDate": {$addToSet:{date:"$yearMonthDay"}}
        } 
    }, 
    {$unwind: "$visitedDate"},
    {$sort: {"visitedDate":1}},
    {$group: 
        {
            _id: "$_id", 
            visitDate: {$push: "$visitedDate"}
        }
    }
```

]);

This is code to find all date based on user